How to set tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex in Mason?
I am using Neovim and use mason to configure my LSPs. I want to use Tailwind with Dioxus which means I need to setup
"tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": ["class: \"(.*)\""],
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "rust": "html"
},

Heres what I tried, sorry I use astronvim but it's configuration of Mason isn't too different.
return {
  "AstroNvim/astrolsp",
  opts = {
    config = {
      tailwindcss = {
        filetypes = { "rust" },
        settings = {
          tailwindCSS = {
            experimental = {
              classRegex = '["class = "(.*?)""]',
            },
          },
        },
        init_options = {
          userLanguages = {
            rust = "html"
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
}

Am I doing it right, but my editor is being wonky?
